# Android....Not getting JSON respone from darksky weather API using Okhttp

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, okhttp

I am writing code to build a simple weather app using [Darksky](https://darksky.net/dev) API
Following is my java code file.
In which I am using okHttp 3.5.0 and asynchronously calling the darksky API and writing response on the log.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package treehouse.com.stormy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        double latitude=37.8267;
        double longitude=-122.4233;
        String apiKey="Here you would insert your key and I have ofcourse mine";
        String forecastURL="https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

      OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
        Request request=new Request.Builder().url(forecastURL).build();
        Call call=client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                try {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG,"Exception caught: ",e);
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Activity Output**

[image]

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "treehouse.com.stormy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile project(':okhttp-3.5.0')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
```

**Detailed Logcat**

[Logcat](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23851604/)

**My activity is crashing  on the emulator but  it is correctly calling the API and I have checked the API console usage before and after running the code?

**API usage before running the code**

[image]

**API usage after running the code**

[image]

Comment: API request and response is working fine for me (after updating api key). Issue must be something else.

Comment: My request and response are also now working fine and the issue was that since I am behind proxy I needed to provide proxy to the android emulator setting to make it use Internet.So Now  as you can see(on my API usage charts) that I am correctly calling the API but Now my Activity is crashing.

Comment: Good to know its working. Try to see what is found in logs. And if it is a different issue that could not be solved, consider opening a new ticket.

Comment: Did you check error? Put your stacktrace.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin I have already posted full logcat please see that.

Comment: FYI, For a couple of years I am using https://github.com/dvdme/forecastio-lib-java and is great, at least for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of Okio library which is not compatible with your version of OkHttp, causing the crash when trying to call a nonexistent method. I would advise using the latest version of Okio, but the OkHttp maven library already has the dependency, too.

Just remove the `compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'` line from your gradle file.

Comment: I tried it but after removing the line you are suggesting the code was not even making call to API.

Comment: I haven't noticed you have OkHttp as a local module (why??). Replace the OkHttp dependency in your gradle file with " compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0' ". In case it doesn't work, you may try adding back the Okio dependency, but with the latest version (1.11.0)